# How can I get the Player Score to show in a custom book?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a map that has some sort of RPG statistics, and I want them to be shown in a book for the player to see his personal stats.
Is it possible to do that?
And, if so, do the stats update automatically?

Comment: That's what the `score` JSON tag is for: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Raw_JSON_text

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for objectives in raw JSON is:

```
{"score":{"name":"<name>","objective":"<objective>","value":"[value]"}
```

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text):

> score: A player's score in an objective. […] 
>    name: The name of the player whose score should be displayed. […]
>    objective: The internal name of the objective to display the player's score in.
>    value: Optional. If present, this value is used regardless of what the score would have been.

The following command will give a book titled "SomeTitle" by "SomeAuthor" to the nearest player with a single page containing the nearest player's score for someObjective:

```
give @p written_book{pages:["[\"\",{\"score\":{\"name\":\"@p\",\"objective\":\"someObjective\"}}]"],title:SomeTitle,author:SomeAuthor}
```

However, this will not automatically update if the score changes.